# how to take Images from camera 3 times using forloop

Tags: android

This is my code below is browse button and take image from camera and display on screen is fine but I want to nuse for loop to do this 3 times programmatically I mean  for i = 1 to 2  is browse button take image and show so screen show 3 button 3 images  using for loop how do I do this?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public  static Bitmap yourSelectedImage = null;
private final int CAMERA_PICTURE = 1;
private final int GALLERY_PICTURE = 2;
private Intent pictureActionIntent = null;
public final String SDCARD_ROOT_PATH =    
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
public final String SAVE_PATH_IN_SDCARD = "/myFolder23/"; 
public final String IMAGE_CAPTURE_NAME    
 ="imgtemp"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpeg"; 

ImageView imageView1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout btnLO = new LinearLayout(this);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsLO = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    // button margins
    paramsLO.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    // button height/width *pixels*
    paramsLO.height = 75;
    paramsLO.width = 75;

    btnLO.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    btnLO.setBackgroundColor(5); // not working correctly

    //buttons
    Button b1 = new Button(this);








    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {               
        //      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        //      intent.setType("image/*");
         //     startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

                startDialog();
            }
        });        




//    int i1Btn = 0;
//    ImageButton i1 = new ImageButton(this);
 //   i1Btn = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
 ///   i1.setImageResource(i1Btn);





     imageView1 = new ImageView(this);





    //text for buttons
    b1.setText("Arrow");


    //displays buttons with parameters (if any)
    btnLO.addView(b1, paramsLO);

//    btnLO.addView(i1, paramsLO);

    btnLO.addView(imageView1, paramsLO);

    btnLO.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    this.addContentView(btnLO, new LayoutParams());



}






@Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
   imageReturnedIntent) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);



       if (requestCode == GALLERY_PICTURE) {
            Uri uri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            if (uri != null) {
                // User had pick an image.
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]  
{  android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                final String imageFilePath = cursor.getString(0);
                File photos = new File(imageFilePath);
                yourSelectedImage = decodeFile(photos);
                yourSelectedImage =  
 Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourSelectedImage, 150, 150, true);
                imageView1.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
                cursor.close();
            }
            else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "No Image is selected.",  
Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
        else if (requestCode == CAMERA_PICTURE) {
            if (imageReturnedIntent.getExtras() != null) {
                // here is the image from camera
                yourSelectedImage = (Bitmap)  
imageReturnedIntent.getExtras().get("data");
                imageView1.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);

            }
        }




    }


   private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {
            // decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 <  
  REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale++;
            }

            // decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null,  
 o2);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void startDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        myAlertDialog.setTitle("Upload Pictures Option");
        myAlertDialog.setMessage("How do you want to set your picture?");

        myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("Gallery", new  
 DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                pictureActionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT,  
   null);
                pictureActionIntent.setType("image/*");
                pictureActionIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                startActivityForResult(pictureActionIntent, GALLERY_PICTURE);
            }
        });

        myAlertDialog.setNegativeButton("Camera", new  
DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                pictureActionIntent = new  
 Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);











                File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()  
 + "/myFolder23");
                if(dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()) {
                  // do something here
                 }
                else{
                    //create dir here
                    dir.mkdir(); 
                   }
                 Intent pictureActionIntent = new  
 Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);  


                 pictureActionIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,  
Uri.fromFile(new
                         File(SDCARD_ROOT_PATH +  
 SAVE_PATH_IN_SDCARD,IMAGE_CAPTURE_NAME)));  




                  startActivityForResult(pictureActionIntent,CAMERA_PICTURE);  




            }
        });
        myAlertDialog.show();
    }







@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use the Following Method to capture multiple Images as much as you required

```
private class CaptureThread extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        int count = 0;

        while(count < mNo) {
            mFileName = mLocation + "/pic" + count + ".jpg";

            mCamera.takePicture(null, mPictureCallback, mPictureCallback);

            count++;

            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: nono i want to use forloop to capture image show on screen then capture then show then capture then shw 3 times